# How can we build a query in postgresql to display column value with time datatype as null when extracting it from other column has either 0 or null

Tags: postgresql, time

I am in a fix how can I do this:
I Have view A and B. View A has column mark_time (int datatype) and View B has start_time ( Time data type) in postgresql.
In the view B I am pulling value from View A for column start_time. The logic should be
if mark_time has 0 or Null value the it should show as NUll in start_time in View B else it should take the mark_time value passed through to_timestamp function .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN coalesce(a.mark_time, 0) = 0
            THEN NULL::timestamptz
            ELSE to_timestamp(a.mark_time)
       END
FROM a;
```

Comment: i am able to get null but where value is neither 0 nor null it gives me mark_time but with the day , i think because of the timestaptz , when i change timestamptz to time it throws following error :CASE/WHEN could not convert type time without time zone to timestamp with time zone

Comment: Got it , made some changes . Thank you